# Querying a documents with nested array in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

**EDIT**: Below query were executed from DataGrip, mongodb version `4.2.6`

I am fairly new to mongoDB and I am digging through a lot of documents but couldn't figure out how this would work.

My collections is like this:

```
db.cards.insertMany([
{
  "Name": "SingleFaced Card",
  "Face": [
    {"Type": "Front", "Color": ["Black"]},
  ]
},
{
  "Name": "DoubleFaced Card",
  "Face": [
    {"Type": "Front", "Color": ["Black"]},
    {"Type": "Back", "Color": ["Red", "Yellow"]}
  ]
},
]);
```

I would like to query the card, that has at least one face with the given color, say `Red`.

I have tried lots of different options, all of them give me a count of `0`.

```
db.cards.count({"Face.Color": "Red"}); // 0 record
db.cards.count({"Face.Color": ["Red"]}) // 0 record
db.cards.count({"Face.Color": {$elemMatch:{$in:['Red']}}}) // 0 record
db.cards.count({"Face.Color": {$elemMatch:{$all:['Red']}}}) // 0 record
db.cards.count({"Face.Color": {$elemMatch:{$elemMatch:{$in:['Red']}}}}); // 0 record
```

I initially thought there is something wrong with my installation, but the below queries on nested fields worked.

```
db.cards.count({"Face.Type" : "Front"}); // 2 record
db.cards.count({"Face.Type" : "Back"}); // 1 record
```

Any suggestions on how should I make this work? Am I using the wrong design choice here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third query [already works](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NA3_Sk2gjw9)

```js
db.cards.count({ "Face.Color": { $elemMatch: { $in: ['Red'] } } })
```

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I did some comparison on the environment. I was running the examples through DataGrip from JetBrain on mongodb 4.2.6.  I have downgraded the db version to 4.2.5 and re-run the query from python package `pymongo` and it works now. Perhaps there is a bug on either DataGrip or version 4.2.6